# SQL query to get combination of two columns of different tables in chronological order

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures

```
---------------------------------
| table_one.col_a| table_one.fk |
---------------------------------
| A              | 4            |
---------------------------------
| B              | 4            |
---------------------------------
| C              | 4            |
---------------------------------

---------------------------------
| table_two.col_b|table_two.fk  |
---------------------------------
| E              | 4            |
---------------------------------
| F              | 4            |
---------------------------------
| G              | 4            |
---------------------------------
| H              | 4            |
---------------------------------
```

I am looking for a query which will out put something like this, when fk is common foreign key

```
 A_E
 B_F
 C_G
  _H
```

Comment: What do you mean by "chronological order"? Is there a field you can sort on to get the rows chronologically?

Comment: Unless you do a order by mysql will not return rows in a particular order.

Comment: Do you have an autoincrement field on both tables?

Comment: You need more fields on your tables, otherwise you can only link as follows: A_E, A_F, A_G, A_H, B_E, B_F, B_G, B_H, etc. MySQL does not automatically know what time a row was added - you need a field for that.

Comment: sorry guys I forget to mention about the primary key field id [with auto-increment] in both tables.

Comment: @sumit - then please update your question with the relevant information, including that it's not actually 'chronological order', but in the order of the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Variables to create a counter field:

e.g.

```
SELECT  col_a,
        fk,
        @r:= CASE WHEN @FK = fk THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowNumber,
        @fk:= fk
FROM    table_one, 
        (SELECT @fk:= 0) fk,
        (SELECT @r:= 0) r
ORDER BY fk, col_a;
```

Will return

```
+-------+----+-----------+
| col_a | fk | RowNumber |
+-------+----+-----------+
|  A    | 4  |    1      |
|  B    | 4  |    2      |
|  C    | 4  |    3      |
+-------+----+-----------+
```

Here you **must** order by the partitioning field first, e.g. if you want rownumbers to reset to 1 for each `fk` you have to order by this first. Then your next order by determines what order the `RowNumber` is applied in. So if you changed to:

```
ORDER BY fk, col_a DESC;
```

You would get:

```
+-------+----+-----------+
| col_a | fk | RowNumber |
+-------+----+-----------+
|  C    | 4  |    1      |
|  B    | 4  |    2      |
|  A    | 4  |    3      |
+-------+----+-----------+
```

*Note the RowNumbers for A and C are now different*

So if you do the same thing for both tables, you can then join on `fk` and `RowNumber`:

```
SELECT  b.fk, CONCAT(COALESCE(a.col_a, ''), '_', COALESCE(b.Col_b, '')) AS ColA_ColB
FROM    (   SELECT  col_b,
                    fk,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN @FK = fk THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowNumber,
                    @fk:= fk
            FROM    table_two, 
                    (SELECT @fk:= 0) fk,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) r
            ORDER BY fk, col_b
        ) b
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  col_a,
                    fk,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN @FK = fk THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowNumber,
                    @fk:= fk
            FROM    table_one, 
                    (SELECT @fk:= 0) fk,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) r
            ORDER BY fk, col_a
        ) a
            ON b.fk = a.fk
            AND b.RowNumber = a.RowNumber;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca37/5)**

If you don't know which table will contain more record, since MySQL doesn't support full joins the query gets a bit more complicated, you need to do a `UNION ALL` to merge the datasets:

```
SELECT  a.fk,
        a.RowNumber,
        CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN TableSource = 1 THEN Col ELSE '' END), 
                '_',
                MAX(CASE WHEN TableSource = 2 THEN Col ELSE '' END)) AS Col_AB
FROM    ((  SELECT  col_b AS Col,
                    fk,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN @FK = fk THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowNumber,
                    @fk:= fk,
                    2 AS TableSource
            FROM    table_two, 
                    (SELECT @fk:= 0) fk,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) r
            ORDER BY fk, col_b
        )
        UNION ALL
        (   SELECT  col_a,
                    fk,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN @FK = fk THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowNumber,
                    @fk:= fk,
                    1 AS TableSource
            FROM    table_one, 
                    (SELECT @fk:= 0) fk,
                    (SELECT @r:= 0) r
            ORDER BY fk, col_a
        )) a
GROUP BY a.fk, a.RowNumber;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca37/11)**

---

**EDIT**

With thanks due to [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m), these two queries can be tidied up as follows:

- JOIN method:

  ```
  SELECT  b.fk, CONCAT(COALESCE(a.col_a, ''), '_', COALESCE(b.Col_b, '')) AS ColA_ColB
  FROM    (   SELECT  col_b,
                      @r:= (@fk = fk) * @r + 1 AS RowNumber,
                      @fk:= fk AS fk
              FROM    table_two, 
                      (SELECT @fk:= 0, @r:= 0) r
              ORDER BY fk, col_b
          ) b
          LEFT JOIN
          (   SELECT  col_a,
                      @r:= (@fk = fk) * @r + 1 AS RowNumber,
                      @fk:= fk AS fk
              FROM    table_one, 
                      (SELECT @fk:= 0, @r:= 0) r
              ORDER BY fk, col_a
          ) a
              ON b.fk = a.fk
              AND b.RowNumber = a.RowNumber;
  ```
- UNION method:

  ```
  SELECT  a.fk,
          a.RowNumber,
          CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN TableSource = 1 THEN Col ELSE '' END), 
                  '_',
                  MAX(CASE WHEN TableSource = 2 THEN Col ELSE '' END)) AS Col_AB
  FROM    ((  SELECT  col_b AS Col,
                      @r:= (@fk = fk) * @r + 1 AS RowNumber,
                      @fk:= fk AS fk,
                      2 AS TableSource
              FROM    table_two, 
                      (SELECT @fk:= 0, @r:= 0) s
              ORDER BY fk, col_b
          )
          UNION ALL
          (   SELECT  col_a,
                      @r:= (@fk = fk) * @r + 1 AS RowNumber,
                      @fk:= fk AS fk,
                      1 AS TableSource
              FROM    table_one, 
                      (SELECT @fk:= 0, @r:= 0) s
              ORDER BY fk, col_a
          )) a
  GROUP BY a.fk, a.RowNumber;
  ```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca37/16)**

Comment: +1 and a couple of minor notes: You can both assign an expression to a variable and return the result as a column in one go, so `fk, ..., @fk := fk` can be replaced with just `@fk := fk AS fk`. You can place it after the `@r` assignment so that the previous value of `@fk` is tested before getting overwritten. Also, the initialisation SELECTs can be combined. For an illustration, see all those points addressed [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca37/12) in a query added after yours (one other change is a more concise `RowNumber` expression).

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks, I have edited accordingly (and learned something new).

Answer (score -1):

Use left

```
select concat(col_a,'_',col_b) from 
table_one left outer join table_two using(fk)
```

Comment: -1 - this gets nowhere near the desired output, as it's going to give a full Cartesian product for the given fk.

Comment: A         _E         
A         _F         
A         _G         
A         _H         
B         _E         
B         _F         
B         _G         
B         _H         
C         _E         
C         _F         
C         _G         
C         _H     like this !!

Comment: ok, I see. so you need something like this

select concat(col_a,'_',col_b) from
(select col_a, fk, (select count(1)  from a as tmp where col_a<a.col_a)+1 rownum from a) as tmp_a left outer join
(select col_b, fk, (select count(1) from b as tmp where col_b<b.col_b)+1 rownum from b) as tmp_b using(fk,rownum)

Comment: this is not a perfect way, because there a lot of subqueries.